# How to pass value between method android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods

I know that I'm asking a silly question, I'm new in android. I'm currently developing an android app with eclipse. I only want to know how to pass value between method in android. I want to pass value from onCreate() to onClick()

```
package com.example.anagramslayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Story1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String x = "hello";

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){

         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the value of the String "x"?

Declare it as a class field.  It will then be available to all methods of the class.

```
package com.example.anagramslayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Story1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private String x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        x = "hello";

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){

         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a string value as an argument to your `onClick` method. When you define a method to be triggered `onClick` in a `Button`'s XML, as you have done, it MUST be in the form you listed - i.e. it can only take a View v as its argument.

Just used an instance variable for that class